# Multithreaded FTP download

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp

I'm trying to process a certain FTP directory which holds several directories and in turn those directories have an arbitrary number of files. So what I'm trying to do is to have 1 thread for each of the subdirectories and each thread to be concerned with the respective sub-dir here is what I came up:

```
private void fetchFilesFromFTP() {

    try {
        client.connect("ftp.ncbi.nih.gov");
        client.login("anonymous", "anonymous");

        client.changeWorkingDirectory("genomes/Fungi");

        FTPFile dirs[] = client.listDirectories();
        dirsToDl.addAndGet(dirs.length); 

        for (final FTPFile ftpFile : dirs) {
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                //process each FTP directory in a new thread
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processFTPdir(ftpFile.getName());
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FungiProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FungiProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}

private void processFTPdir(String dir) {

    File f = new File(destination + File.separator + dir);
    if (!f.mkdirs()) {
        System.out.println("Error creating dir for " + dir);
        return;
    }

    FTPFile files[];
    try {
        //we are already in the correct directory
        files = client.listFiles(dir, new FTPFileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(FTPFile ftpf) {
                return ftpf.getName().endsWith(".gbk");
            }
        });

        for (FTPFile fTPFile : files) {
            FileOutputStream fout =  new FileOutputStream(destination + File.separator + dir + File.separator + fTPFile.getName());
            if (client.retrieveFile(dir + "/" + fTPFile.getName(), fout)) {

                System.out.println("successfully downloaded");
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
            }
            System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FungiProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if(dirsToDl.decrementAndGet() == 0) latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

The sequential version of the code works - I can see files ending with .gbk actually being downloaded whereas with the multithreaded version only the respective subdirectories are created but no files are downloaded. I don't even get any errors. Is is possible that FTP doesn't support multiple file downloads at once?

Comment: But each thread uses the same FTP connection or opens a separate connection?

Comment: uses the same connection. That's why I said that I didn't now if FTP as a protocol supported this

Comment: Via threads?  I highly doubt it would.  All the threads would share the same client (and thus, the same command channel), and FTP doesn't provide a way to do the kind of multiplexing you'd need in order to make it work.  (Responses to two threads' commands look pretty much the same; there's no way for FTP to say "this is a response to command 1".)

Comment: @chao okay, that's what i wanted to know, I guess it would be better if you make this as a response

Comment: Just did.  I wasn't going to at first, but considering the upvotes i got on the comment... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is to have one tread with its own client connect to the server and create a  list of paths of the files you want to download. Then you start up a number of threads, each with its own client, that grabs the first from the list and starts downloading the file.

The number of concurrent connections that you can have to one ftp-server is limited by the settings of that server.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt this would work with multiple threads. All the threads would share the same client (and thus, the same command channel), and FTP doesn't provide a way to do the kind of multiplexing you'd need in order to make it work. (Responses to two threads' commands look pretty much the same; there's no way for FTP to say "this is a response to command 1".)

You'd have to have each thread grab a lock before sending a command and unlock only after getting a response...forcing one command at a time to run, and serializing things so much that you'd lose all the benefits of multithreading anyway.  The only way around that would be to use a client per thread, but then you'll end up running into per-user connection limits (which tend to be pretty strict).

All in all, this sounds like a job for a single thread.